# How do I format a string to be multi-line in a JavaScript prompt?

Tags: javascript, string, newline

I'm trying to offer the user multi-line selectable text using a `prompt()` dialog. I will format the text in JavaScript, insert special characters and then throw up the prompt and all the user has to do is hit Ctrl-C, because the text is already selected.

When the prompt is displayed, the selectable text will look like this:

```
Line1□Line2□Line3□
```

where the `□` is the newline character. It all gets displayed in one line, so it's easily selectable, but pasting it into Notepad or any other text editor should result in this:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

I tried `\r` and `\n` and even `\r\n`, but it seems to truncate it to the first line.

How can I do this?

Comment: `prompt` is always a one-line input. Why not create a custom element (popup-like) which contains the text?

Comment: Do a normal alert and press control+c to copy the content of the dialog, should at least work on windows.

Comment: @Fox32 Why didn't I think of that before! Ctrl+C works on an alert() box! Why don't you post this as an answer so i can pick it as the correct one? :-)

Comment: @RickHoving a `<br/>` tag will only be rendered as a new line in HTML, but not within conventional text boxes such as the one in `prompt()`.

Comment: @pimvdb This is for use in a very quick (and possibly dirty) solution. I've chosen `prompt()` because it gets displayed faster than it will take for an HTML div to render on screen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (at least on windows) to copy the content of a dialog box (like `alert()` in JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

Won't work: `prompt()` is single line.